# Not highlighting text while hovering over list of navigation bar

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the text of navigation bar, the space above text highlights instead of the text itself. my CSS code is as below:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: silver;
}

li a {
display: block;    
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

My html code is as below:

```
 <ul>
  <li><a href=""></a> Home</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>Contact</li>
    <li> <a href=""></a>Gallery</li>        
  </ul>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML and CSS in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Minimal example please. No need for JSFiddle, just embed example here.

Comment: try `li > a:hover` :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it is not working. thanks

Comment: @Sonam aww ok :) how about adding a class to the `<a>` tags and doing `.className:hover {}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at your anchor links, you made a mistake in them, place a link text between . Second apply hover rule over li instead of li a:

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: silver;
}

li a {
display: block;    
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: silver;
}

li a {
display: block;    
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Gallery</a></li>        
  </ul>
```

add text with in `a` tag,  to make the link clickable - and to get your desired result also

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your code and find that the problem is in your html code. try this one.

```
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li> <a href="">Gallery</a></li>        
     </ul>
```

the text should be inside `<a>` tag as you are hovering the `<a>` element.

Answer (score -2):

Just change `li a:hover` to `li:hover`

```css
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: silver;
    }

    li a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Change the link color on hover */
    li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href=""></a> Home</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>Contact</li>
    <li> <a href=""></a>Gallery</li>        
  </ul>
```